# insert and update file in google drive with javascript

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

the authentification works but i am not able to insert a file, or to update it. i copy exactly the javascript code from https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert and call the insertFile function after authentification but in this function i never get into reader.onload = function(e) {...}

what should be the fileData object?

i only want to create a file containing an json object and update this file some times.

Answer (score 1):

fileData is the blob you want to insert. The sample is using the File API, learn more about it on http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Comment: ok, i have read the article and also some others but i still dont know how to get it work. the fileData must be an js object i think. but how is the construct of this object? or how i get this object.